# How to push data to elasticsearch from dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch

I am trying to use elastic search libraries like `pyelasticsearch` and `elasticsearch` I am not getting any method where i can pass dataframe and that method will load data frame data to elastic search.

I am trying a this code:

```
for i,df in enumerate(csvfile): 
print (i)
records=df.where(pd.notnull(df), None).T.to_dict()
list_records=[records[it] for it in records]
print(list_records)
try :
    es.bulk_index("call_demo_data1","tweet",list_records)
except :
    print ("error!, skiping some tweets sorry")
    pass
```

where csvfile is my dataframe where my all data is present. but I am getting following error

```
'str' object has no attribute 'where'
```

I have used recommendation in comments

Now that problem is solved I am getting this error while bulk loading

I am using above method to load data elastic search I was facing problem so here is the link to the question I posted earlier

Here is the code I am using now :

```
records= csvfile.T.to_dict()
list_records=[records[it] for it in records]
#print(list_records)
es.bulk_index("call_demo_data1","tweet",list_records)
```

Error I am getting is :

```
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

this error is coming while bulk indexing. csvfile in above code is a data frame. I am using this liabrary `pyelasticsearch`

This is the error traceback 
[image: Traceback]

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you actually make a DataFrame...? The error comes long before trying to push data to elasticsearch

Comment: @roganjosh `records=df.where(pd.notnull(df), None).T.to_dict()` this lines comtains where

Comment: I have created dataframe named csvfile in my code above and that dataframe contains record when i do `csvfile.head()` it is printing data

Comment: No it doesn't. Unless you explicitly create the dataframe, calling something `df` will not automatically make it as such. `df` in your case it just a string being read from a csv file.

Comment: Ok, so if you have a dataframe already, why iterate through it like this?

Comment: ok. so what i need to do in this case. I am stuck in this approach.

Comment: I am new to python I followed this approch from one of github solution from here `https://gist.github.com/clemsos/8668698`

Comment: It would seem that `enumerate()` destroys your dataframe in some way and you end up back with strings. You cannot call the `where` method anymore.

Comment: I'm guessing here; get rid of the for loop. `records = csvfile.dropna().T.to_dict()`

Comment: i tried using ur recommendation like this `records= csvfile.T.to_dict()
list_records=[records[it] for it in records]
#print(list_records)
es.bulk_index("call_demo_data1","tweet",list_records)

print ("done in %.3fs"%(time()-t0))`      i am getting following error in es.bulk_index error is   `too many values to unpack (expected 2)
`

Comment: @roganjosh please review above error

Comment: You need to edit all this into the question and provide the full traceback. Perhaps some progress has been made here. There's no way any of us can make sense of that comment.

Comment: That's not the traceback, that's the error. Please include the whole traceback.